# How do i create a container in constraintlayout so i can set a background?

Tags: java, android, xml, android-constraintlayout

How can i group views in a constraint layout without nesting viewgroups?

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
  xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  android:orientation="vertical"
  android:background="@color/color1">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/mAlbumArtLarge"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:scaleType="fitXY"
    android:src="@drawable/image1"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    tools:ignore="ContentDescription" />

<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    android:id="@+id/mBottomSheet"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#20000000"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <ImageView
         android:id="@+id/mAlbumIvBottom"
         android:layout_width="50dp"
         android:layout_height="50dp"
         android:layout_margin="5dp"
         android:scaleType="fitXY"
         app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
         app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
         app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

This is what i'm doing now to create a container `mBottomSheet` where i can group views and set a background, but i'm using another viewgroup `constraintlayout` for this which is not recommended because the point of constraintlayout is too have a flat view hierarchy.

So how can i achieve the same thing, but without using another viewgroup as a container?

**EDIT**

example:

[image]

Comment: it is recommended but not required. just make sure not to nest too deep.

Comment: @user1506104 So performance wise it wouldn't have a big impact if i have like 1-2 childview viewgroups (linear/relative) inside a constraintlayout?

Comment: yes. if there is, you would recognize right away.

Comment: @user1506104 Ok thanks for the info, seems like im good because im not noticing any lag.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [Gudeliens](https://constraintlayout.com/basics/guidelines.html) to achieve something similar.

For example, you can take some view (let's call it `x`) and place on your layout and just put all your wanted views above `x`.

As for the Gudeliens, with them, you can place your `x` in any way that you would want to use using `app:layout_constraintGuide_percent` attribute.

**Take this layout for example:**

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout 
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
  xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
  android:orientation="vertical">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/mAlbumIvBottom"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:background="@drawable/ic_launcher_background"
    android:scaleType="fitXY"
    android:elevation="6dp"
    android:layout_margin="6dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/guideline6"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/guideline7"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/button2" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button2"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:text="I am view x"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/guideline6"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />


<android.support.constraint.Guideline
    android:id="@+id/guideline6"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    app:layout_constraintGuide_percent=".15" />

<android.support.constraint.Guideline
    android:id="@+id/guideline7"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    app:layout_constraintGuide_percent=".3" />


</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

**This layout will look like this without any nesting views:** (I am adding preview image to you could better understand guidelines)

[image]

The layout above is an example of how you could achieve this without using nested view groups.

---

This solution will work for you but I also agree with *user1506104*.
It's ok to have a very small level of nesting, if you don't overdo it your layout performance could stay the same

- You can either go with my solution or have some nesting views (again, don't overdo it)
  I prefer to use my solution so I can avoid nesting.
- Just remember that my solution may be a bit longer than just having some lever of nesting when creating your layout.

Comment: Thanks for your response, but what i want to achieve is a container where i can set a background color. For example views inside a linearlayout with a white background which acts like a container for these views, i want to achieve the same thing but without the need of the linearlayout.

Comment: Isn't that exactly what I did? you have the button with the id `button2`, you can change its background color or even the type of the view. and it looks exactly like what you described.

Comment: I edited my post to clarify what i meant, because i'm not sure what you mean. As you can see in my example now, im using a linearlayout as a container with a black background, how can i do this without using that linearlayout so i can avoid nesting.

Comment: Oh ok, the best way I can explain it is like this: I have used my button instead of your `linearlayout` container (This cause the no nesting situation). Now after I have the button all I did was to constraint my other views to it. The other views are not inside the button - they are only constrained to it and above the button(so you could see them). You can change the button in any way you will choose too, starting from its color, size, positioning and more.

Comment: If any of this was not understandable feel free to ask

Comment: I think i understand it, but isn't it weird using a button as a container?

Comment: It's very weird, I really don't know why I chose the button for the example, just replace the button tag with `View` or anything else that you want.

Comment: Ok thanks this works for keeping a flat view hierarchy, but what you also mentioned in your answer, if i use like 1 linearlayout inside my constraintlayout it shouldn't impact the performance? The documentation is really vague about constraintlayout, people say nesting is really bad, but others say we can nest layouts?

Comment: About that - I prefer not to nest at all if possible even if making the layout will take more time. Maybe if you add only 1 `linearlayout` inside your `constraintlayout` it won't affect performance. but then again - I would not do it and would rather stay with 0 nested view groups. If you can avoid nesting no matter how deep the nesting level is maybe you should consider to do so.

Answer (score -1):

You can try:
androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Group

or

You can group your Views together by assigning Constraints with respect to each others position but you won't be able to apply a background on all of the widgets as they are still the child of the parent ViewGroup. There are many other options to avoid using nested ConstraintLayout.

1. You can use another ViewGroup like LinearLayout or RelativeLayout inside ConstraintLayout.
2. You can create a seperate layout for BottomSheet and include it, for clean code

Comment: But using either LinearLayout or RelativeLayout as a child view in a constraintLayout would go against constraintlayouts flat view hierarchy, isn't nesting viewgroups in constraint considered bad performance wise?

Comment: That's what view group are for, No it won't impact on performance because your bottom sheet is a separate group. If you don't use subgroup for Bottom sheet then the Widget of the Bottom sheet will be a direct child of parent Constraint Layout and sibling of other widgets. Which is not a good hierarchy